# Why async.map returns multiple copies of array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

```
const async = require('async');

const arr = [
    { name: 'john', id: '1' },
    { name: 'Andrie', id: '2' }]

let collectArr = [];
let data = async.mapLimit(arr, 5, async function (input) {

    collectArr.push({ name: input.name, id: input.id });
    return collectArr;
})

data.then((result) =>{
    console.log('success',result);
}).catch(e => console.log('err'));
```

So here i am providing array to async.mapLimit without callback and expecting promise here.
Expected Output :- [ { name: 'john', id: '1' }, { name: 'Andrie', id: '2' } ] ,

Got Result :-

[ [ { name: 'john', id: '1' }, { name: 'Andrie', id: '2' } ],
[ { name: 'john', id: '1' }, { name: 'Andrie', id: '2' } ] ]

So my question is why it is creating multiple copies of array, how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are needlessly returning a sub array, and the same array reference each iteration, when all you want is to return the new object.

```
let data = async.mapLimit(arr, 5, async function (input) {
    return { name: input.name, id: input.id };   
});
```

Not sure why you need this to be async

Comment: Can you provide some guides on async, because i am not able to find it where all the information is described. Official docs are not that much good

Comment: I've never used this library but concept is the same as Array#map() with slight difference for limit argument

Comment: Ok i will go through map and check it out